# SQL Server 2008 R2: Converting data type varchar to geometry

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, geometry

I am updating table with some values with Geometry Path Condition.

Here in the following example: I am passing table name as `@Table`,`@ColumnA`(for setting new values),`@GeoPath`(to check in 
the condition) for the dynamic scipt as shown below:

```
@Table = 'Table1'

@ColumnA = 'A'

@GeoPath = 0xE610000001040500000061574D5E31433140000000003EAF52405E3B0D825B92314000000000AACA52407BEECBC0FB263140000000001

SET @query =    'Update ['+@Table+']
                 SET ColumnA = '''+@ColumnA+'''
                 WHERE CONVERT(Geometry,'+CAST(@GeoPath AS varchar(MAX))+').STIntersects(geometry::Point(Latitude,Longitude, 4326))= 1';
PRINT(@query);

EXECUTE(@query);
```

But getting the error:

> Error converting data type varchar to geometry.

Comment: What is in your variables?

Comment: @Paddy, Okay! Let me edit it.

Comment: @jarlh, Thank you for editing. Can you please help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

When working with `GEOGRAPHY` or `GEOMETRY` you need to specify  more information instead of just converting from one type to another.

For example this is conversion of polygon binary data back into geography type.

```
DECLARE @g geography; 
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromWKB(0x01030000000100000005000000F4FDD478E9965EC0DD24068195D3474083C0CAA145965EC0508D976E12D3474083C0CAA145965EC04E62105839D44740F4FDD478E9965EC04E62105839D44740F4FDD478E9965EC0DD24068195D34740, 4326);
SELECT @g
```

here is same example but this time from text

```
DECLARE @g_text geography; 
SET @g_text = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON ((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326);
SELECT @g_text
```

I'm not sure what type of binary data you have in order to convert it. Just make sure that you are using correct conversion method.

Read more on [`geography::STPolyFromText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933969(v=sql.105).aspx)